# Calculate percent change over time in dataframe with noncontiguous dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:
`df`

```
   Name        Date ID  Amount
0  Faye  2018-12-31  A       2
1  Faye  2019-03-31  A       1
2  Faye  2019-06-30  B       5
3  Faye  2019-09-30  B       2
4  Faye  2019-09-30  A       4
5  Faye  2020-03-31  A       1
6  Mike  2018-12-31  A       4
7  Mike  2019-03-31  B       2
8  Mike  2019-03-31  C       1
9  Mike  2019-06-30  A       3
```

And for each `Name`, `Date`, `ID`, group I calculate the % change of `Amount` from the previous `Date` in a new column. If there was no previous entry, then I add `New`:

```
df['% Change'] = (df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Name', 'ID']).Amount.pct_change())
df['% Change'] = df['% Change'].fillna('New')
```

But if the `ID` disappears for a few `Dates` (e.g., `ID` `A` is present for `Faye` in `2018-12-31` and `2019-03-31`, but disappears for the `2019-06-30` period), I want the next time it appears to show as `New` again so that the output looks like:

```
   Name        Date ID  Amount % Change
0  Faye  2018-12-31  A       2      New
1  Faye  2019-03-31  A       1     -0.5
2  Faye  2019-06-30  B       5      New
3  Faye  2019-09-30  B       2     -0.6
4  Faye  2019-09-30  A       4      New
5  Faye  2020-03-31  A       1      New
6  Mike  2018-12-31  A       4      New
7  Mike  2019-03-31  B       2      New
8  Mike  2019-03-31  C       1      New
9  Mike  2019-06-30  A       3      New
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: All of your dates are quarter-ends except row 5. Is it supposed to be Mar 31?

Comment: Yes sorry, I've updated row 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expected result contains an error, sorting it will make it easier toooo see:

```
>>> expected.sort_values(['Name', 'ID', 'Date'])
   Name       Date ID  Amount %_Change
0  Faye 2018-12-31  A       2      New
1  Faye 2019-03-31  A       1     -0.5
4  Faye 2019-09-30  A       4      New
5  Faye 2020-03-31  A       1    -0.75  <-- shouldn't this be "New" since 2020-12-31 was missing?
2  Faye 2019-06-30  B       5      New
3  Faye 2019-09-30  B       2     -0.6
6  Mike 2018-12-31  A       4      New
9  Mike 2019-06-30  A       3      New
7  Mike 2019-03-31  B       2      New
8  Mike 2019-03-31  C       1      New
```

With that said, you can right a custom `percent_change` function to resample each `(Name, ID)` group to quarterly before calculating the percentage change:

```
def percent_change(group):
    amount = group[['Date', 'Amount']].set_index('Date')
    return amount.pct_change(fill_method=None, freq='Q').rename(columns={'Amount': '% Change'})

result = (
    df.sort_values('Date')
        .groupby(['Name', 'ID'])
        .apply(percent_change)
        .fillna('New')
        .merge(df, how='right', on=['Name', 'ID', 'Date'])
)
```

Result:

```
   Name ID       Date % Change  Amount
0  Faye  A 2018-12-31      New       2
1  Faye  A 2019-03-31     -0.5       1
2  Faye  A 2019-09-30      New       4
3  Faye  A 2020-03-31      New       1
4  Faye  B 2019-06-30      New       5
5  Faye  B 2019-09-30     -0.6       2
6  Mike  A 2018-12-31      New       4
7  Mike  A 2019-06-30      New       3
8  Mike  B 2019-03-31      New       2
9  Mike  C 2019-03-31      New       1
```

---

### A faster version

For the record, I randomly generate a 2M rows dataframe with the following code:

```
import string

n = 2_000_000
qend = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2019-12-31', freq='Q')

np.random.seed(42)
names = list(map(''.join, np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), (n, 3))))
dates = np.random.choice(qend, n)
ids = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), n)
amounts = np.random.randint(1, 100, n)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': names,
    'Date': dates,
    'ID': ids,
    'Amount': amounts
})
```

It assumes all dates are quarter-ends and that they are of Timestamp data type. Explanation provided in the comment

```
# Make a sorted copy of the original dataframe
tmp = df.sort_values(['Name', 'ID', 'Date'])

# When we call a GroupBy, we lose the original index
# so let's keep a copy here
tmp['OriginalIndex'] = tmp.index

# Calculate day difference between consecutive rows.
# It is a lot faster than `groupby(...)['Date'].diff()`
# but it gives wrong result for the first row of each
# group. The first row of each group should be NaN. It's
# an easy fix and we will deal with it later
tmp['DayDiff'] = tmp['Date'].diff() / pd.Timedelta(days=1)

# This has the same problem as `DayDiff` above but you will
# see that it's irrelevant to our problem
tmp['% Change'] = tmp['Amount'].pct_change()

# The index of the first row in each group
first_indexes = tmp.groupby(['Name', 'ID'])['OriginalIndex'].first()

# Fix the issue in `DayDiff`: the first row of each group
# should be NaN
tmp.loc[first_indexes, 'DayDiff'] = np.nan

# Now this is the key to the whole problem: a quarter lasts a
# maximum of 92 days. If `DayDiff <= 92`, the percentage change
# formula applies. Otherwise, `DayDiff` is either NaN or >92.
# In both cases, the percentage change is NaN.
pct_change = tmp['% Change'].where(tmp['DayDiff'] <= 92, np.nan).fillna('New')

# Assign the result back to frame
df['% Change'] = pct_change
```

Comment: Thanks, you're correct that there was an error in the desired output so I've updated it. However I get a `NotImplementedError` when running your solution.

Comment: Can you check your pandas version? I'm using 1.0

Comment: I'm using 1.0.3

Comment: Did you forget `set_index` in the `percent_change` function?

Comment: Hmm no I don't think so. I copied and pasted your code in its entirety

Comment: This is everything I used to answer your question: https://pastebin.com/GNLvpvVM

Comment: Could this be the issue? `Name: object`, `Date: object`, `ID: object`, `Amount: int64`

Comment: Ah... I think you found it. Convert the Date column to Timestamp please

Comment: Ah is there a way to do it without converting it, or is it a lot easier if it's timestamp?

Comment: It’s always better to use the proper data type. There is a vast array of functions that can’t be used if the dates are in strings

Comment: Okay. I'm trying this on my full dataset (1.9m rows) and it seems to be taking quite a while, even though I have 32Gb of RAM and 2.6ghz 6core i7. Is there a more performant way of running this?

Comment: That's quite an ask for a meager 25 points but I'll bite because it's fun! See my edited answer above. Finished in about 5 seconds on my 2.6 GHz quad-core i7 with 16GB of memory.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how do I make it worth more 25points? Or is that only possible once it's eligible for a bounty?

Comment: I was just joking. 25 pts are enough. Glad that I helped with your problem

Comment: I'm happy to award more if that's possible!